# Does an ordered Map knows how to search efficiently for a key in Scala?

Tags: performance, scala, dictionary, lookup

Does an ordered Map knows how to search efficiently for a key in Scala?
Imagine I have a Map:

```
val unorderdMap: Map[Int, String] = ...
val orederedMap: Map[Int, String] = unorderedMap.sort
```

Is lookup operation for a key faster in orderedMap?

```
unorderedMap.get(i)  //Slower???
orderedMap.get(i)    //Faster???
```

Does the compliler knows how to search efficiently?

Does the compiler performs the lookup operation differently in each case?

*EDIT:
I have a

```
 case class A(key: Int, value1: String, value2: String, ...)
 val SeqA: Seq[A] = Seq(A(1, "One", "Uno", ...), A(2, "Two", "Duo",...), ..., A(20000,... ,...))
```

I want to have fast lookup operations on key(That's what i am interested ONLY)
Is it better to make a Map out of it like:

```
val mapA = SeqA.map(a => a.key -> a)(collection.breakOut)
```

Or Is it Better to leave it as a Sequence(and maybe order them).
Then If I make it a Map should I Order it or not? *Elements are around 
20K - 30K elements!

Comment: What's `sortsomehow` exactly?

Comment: The same Map but Sorted!

Comment: Technically it depends on the actual implementations used (Map is an interface and your sample doesn't specify how you created the map and Map doesn't have a `sort` method). But assuming you're using the scala defaults (HashMap and SortedMap) then MichelLemay's answer is correct.

Comment: @Spartan; The keys of a standard `Map` have no order. You can order them outside of the `Map` but inside the `Map` there is no order. Note: Does not apply to `SortedMap` whose keys are always ordered and cannot be unordered.

Comment: @Spartan how would you "sort" a map? There is a `SortedMap` class, but that's not "a map, that was sorted somehow" ("sorting" a map doesn't actually make any sense), it's just a particular implementation of a map, that is based on it's keys being ordered. These are typically slower than a "standard" map, that's based on hashing the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Sorted maps are usually(*) slower than hash maps in any languages.  This is because sorted maps has O(log n) complexity compared to hash maps which have O(1) amortized complexity.

You should have a look at relevant wiki pages for a more in depth explanation.

(*) That depends on many factors like the size of the map.  For small sets, sorted arrays with binary searches might do better if it fits in cache.

Comment: This also depends greatly on the speed and quality of the hash function you use.